# Why am I forced to code a rowediting event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with a button (Template field/LinkButton) that loads another control, but I was getting a runtime error when clicking the button until I added the following:

```
protected void gvLoans_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Why?  I don't want to allow editing.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely have the event handler assigned in the markup (aspx/ascx). If you remove the event handler assignment you can remove the event handler in the code behind.

Also, make sure you are not [enabling the built in editing functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4245bb4.aspx) which could happen if you provide a CommandButton with a CommandName of "Edit".

Comment: Thanks, but I'm back where I started now. I removed onrowediting="gvLoans_RowEditing" from the markup and I got the runtime error: "The GridView 'gvLoans' fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I changed the CommandName. I made it CommandName="Show" (instead of "Edit"). I would give you points if I could, but I can't with this user.